# Infinite request on ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on an app where user can heart(like) stories. I am trying to implement it with ajax. I have a StoriesController with the heart action. Whenever the heart(like) is clicked, I have responded with heart.js.erb and send a post request. I am working on to update the number of hearts when the user clicks the heart link. But what I am getting is infinite requests via ajax. Below is the snippet of heart action.

```
# Give your heart to someone
  def heart
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

And ajax request is:

```
$('#heart-story-<%= j params[:id]%>').html('<%= @hearts %>')
$.post("/stories/<%= j params[:id]%>/heart", <%= j params[:id] %>)
console.log("<%= j params[:id] %>")
```

What is the probable reason that I am getting infinite request?
The route is:

```
#Stories
resources :stories, only: [:show, :create, :destroy] do
member do
  get :heart, :unheart
  post :heart, :unheart
end
# Comments
resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified following code in heart.js.erb then it will be infinite:

```
$('#heart-story-<%= j params[:id]%>').html('<%= @hearts %>')
$.post("/stories/<%= j params[:id]%>/heart", <%= j params[:id] %>)
console.log("<%= j params[:id] %>")
```

Post request should only be triggered on button click for once don't use it in heart.js.erb

Comment: Thank you .  I ll give it a shot .

Answer (score 0):

The heart.js.erb view is rendered whenever an AJAX request to this action is successful. You should consider it as a callback for your AJAX request, and not the place where you write the logic for your AJAX request. In this view you must implement the logic that updates the UI after a successful AJAX request.

You should use a remote link, like:

```
<%= link_to '<3', heart_story_path(@story), remote: true %>
```

Then you should remove the AJAX call in you heart.js.erb. It should look like this:

```
$('#heart-story-<%= j params[:id]%>').html('<%= @hearts %>')
```

Comment: So I supposed to remove the post request from the js.erb?